# maven how can I take the path of a module in another module?

Tags: maven

I want to take the path of a module 1 in a module 2, to make a copy from the module 1 to the module 2.

To know th path of a module it's ${project.basedir} but for another module ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague, but it looks like you need to declare a dependency on module2 from module1.

There's also a plugin called [`maven-directory-plugin`](https://github.com/jdcasey/directory-maven-plugin) that may aid you with working wih directories during build.